# Richfaces HtmlColumn style class overwrite

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, el

In JSF you can use EL expression to set the styleClass as follow:

```html
<rich:column>
 <h:outputText value="12" id="sumOfAllValues" styleClass="#{!t330RowItems.showSpecialField ? 'rich-table-green' : 'rich-table-cell'}"/>
</rich:column>
```

Now I am building the table in Java code using org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlColumn the only problem is when do this:

```
htmlColumn.setStyleClass("#{!t330RowItems.showSpecialField ? 'rich-table-green' : 'rich-table-cell'}");
```

The following HTML is generated:

```html
<tbody id="j_id154:tb">
 <tr class="rich-table-row rich-table-firstrow ">
  <td class="rich-table-cell #{!t330RowItems.showSpecialField ? 'rich-table-green' : 'rich-table-cell'}" id="j_id154:0:j_id155">55</td>
 </tr>
```

The problem is it is not evaluating the EL expression.  Any ideas on how I can get it to either have `rich-table-cell` or `rich-table-green` as styleClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it as a fullworthy [`ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) instead of as a plain vanilla `String`. You can create one by [`ExpressionFactory#createValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createValueExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29). You can obtain the expression factory in JSF context by [`Application#getExpressionFactory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getExpressionFactory%28%29).

So, this should do:

```
ValueExpression styleClassVE = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
    .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{!t330RowItems.showSpecialField ? 'rich-table-green' : 'rich-table-cell'}", String.class);

htmlColumn.setStyleClass(styleClassVE);
// or htmlColumn.setValueExpression("styleClass", styleClassVE);
```

Comment: Great this solved a part of the problem where htmlColumn.setValueExpression("styleClass", styleClassVE);  The only thing is the following is now generated: <td class="rich-table-cell rich-table-cell" id="j_id154:1:j_id155">56</td>. If it is not a special row, so there is a duplicate rich-table-cell

Comment: Perhaps you need to replace `'rich-table-cell'` in the condition by `''`? I have no idea what kind of HTML RichFaces will generate under any circumstance and what your exact functional requirement is, so I'm just wildly guessing. It should be sufficient to let the CSS class definition of `.rich-table-green` override any styles set by `.rich-table-cell`.

Comment: Just as side note if the row is a special row it generates the follow:<td class="rich-table-cell rich-table-green" id="j_id154:1:j_id155">56</td>.  Having rich-table-cell and rich-table-green.  But if found a more logical workaround just used your ValueExpression idea to overwrite the style, overwriting only the properties I require.  THANKS!!